# Symfony2 curl and api connection

Tags: php, api, symfony, curl, symfony-2.3

I'm new to Symfony and i'm currently toying with API connection. Let me show you the code i'm trying to get to work, the error i get.

```
/**
* @Route("/api-test/{MembershipType}/{DisplayName}", name="api-test")
*/
public function apiTest($MembershipType, $DisplayName)
{
    $apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.bungie.net/platform/destiny/'.$MembershipType'/Stats/GetMembershipIdByDisplayName/'.$DisplayName'/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('X-API-Key: ' . $apiKey));

    $json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    var_dump($json->Response);
    die;
}
```

Don't mind the var_dump; and die; parts, it's just for testing.

So the error i get is:

```
FatalErrorException: Parse: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

From what i understand it is caused by the "CURL_URL" part etc. My problem here is, that it seems correct according to documentation and answers to other questions posted here that i've read. Or maybe I'm just wrong.

I would really appreciate it, if someone could give me some tips on what i've done wrong.

EDIT:

Didn't want to make a new question, so i thought i'd ask here again. As mentioned in the answers i was previously missing points in concatenation, but after getting that to work my request only returns null. Any tips on that? ;)

EDIT No.2:

Resolved

instead of:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('X-API-Key: ' . $apiKey));
```

it should have been:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-API-Key: ' . $apiKey));
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing points in concatenation. :D

`/'.$MembershipType'/Stats/GetMembershipIdByDisplayName/'.$DisplayName'/'`
`/'.$MembershipType.'/Stats/GetMembershipIdByDisplayName/'.$DisplayName.'/'`

Comment: oh my god, i'm embarrassed now ;P thank you for spotting such a noob mistake

Comment: hey, sorry for troubling you again. I've posted an edit to my previous question. Do you maybe have any idea what's going on here? My guess is that it's something with json_decode that i'm getting wrong.

Comment: Try to dump what's returned by `curl_exec($ch)`

Comment: thank you for your help again, but i've already resolved my issue - i should have written `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-API-Key: ' . $apiKey));` instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('X-API-Key: ' . $apiKey));` I'll edit my post in a moment to provide info for future reference.